# Unable to plot the bar graph for the data set through charts.js library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using charts.js library in angularjs. I am not able to find out the error but neither the graph nor the labels are getting populated. The data is getting stored in the array but I think there is some issue with the code for graph which I have written. I am hitting an api to get the json response which I am using as data set to plot the graph.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.labelArr = []; 
  $scope.valueArr = [];

  $http.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/limit=10")
    .then(function(resp){
       $scope.result = resp.data;
       angular.forEach($scope.result, function(value, key){
         $scope.labelArr.push(value.name);
         $scope.valueArr.push(value.price_usd);
       });
       console.log($scope.labelArr); 
       console.log($scope.valueArr);
    }, function(err){
         $scope.result = "Error";
    });       

   var ctx = document.getElementById("dvCanvas").getContext('2d');

   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'bar',  
       data: {
          labels: $scope.labelArr,
           datasets: [{
               //data: $scope.valueArr,
               label:'# of Votes',
               data: [5626.63, 307.937, 0.214696, 335.513, 58.2737, 296.443, 0.208032, 31.9542, 196.835, 89.7169],
               backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
                ],

                borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                ],

                borderWidth: 1
           }]

       },
       options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: `$http` is asynchronous, your graph has to wait for the data to arrive before you can populate it. Most likely the variables you are using are _undefined_ for this reason. You have to work with promises, or just simply extend you code to: `$http.get(...).then(...).finally(/* section with the graph */)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes, adding the code you suggested worked. If you like, you can post it as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with asynchronous calls always brings confusion. JavaScript solved most of the issues with this by introducing Promises, so you would handle asynchronous callbacks better. Angular has the same concept with `$http` and `$q` services.

Your data arrives asynchronously and in order to use the data from those callbacks you need to deal with the delay. One way is to resolve a promise from `$http.get` function call. The common pattern is:

```
return $http.get(url).then((res) => {
    return res.data;
});
```

Once this is returned from your service / factory that handles the logic for your controller, you can resolve a promise with `your_promise.then((res)=>{ /* main code */ })`

Alternative solutions is to **chain** your promise and execute another section of the code with **finally** in a form: `finally(callback, notifyCallback)`. A common pattern is:

```
$http.get(url).then((res) => {
    $scope.data = res.data;
}).finally(() => {
    // main code where you populate functions with $scope.data
    /* ... */
});
```